# angular ng-show greater than is not evaluating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ng-show

I've been trying for two days to make date filters with input using Rails and angular, but finally I gave up. The format of the date that the input is giving to me is different than the one that I need, and I can't change it.

I think I can do the "filters" in an alternative easiest way. I realized that using ruby I can obtain the dates in the format I need very easy, so I am trying to show and hide the elements comparing the ruby date with the date of the element.

So I am trying this:

```
<section ng-repeat="event in events | orderBy:'date' | filter:myFilter" 
         ng-show="(<%= Date.today.to_s  %> <= {{event.date}})">
```

but the expression `ng-show="(<%= Date.today.to_s  %>) <= ({{event.date}})"` is not evaluating or is always true, because it is showing all the events, including the previous to the date.

I also tried `"(<%= Date.today.to_s  %> <= event.date)"` but this one is always false, so all the elements are hidden...

Somebody can help me?

Edit: the myFilter is set in a similar way to only show today's events, and is working.

```
<a id="filter-by-date" class="btn btn-success wide-btn" href="#" 
   ng-click="myFilter = '<%= Date.today.to_s  %>'">Today Events</a>
```

Comment: without parenthesis is like with parenthesis...

Comment: I believe you don't need curly brackets for `ng-show`. Try this: `ng-show="(<%= Date.today.to_s  %> <= event.date)"`

Comment: this expression seems to be always false, it hides all the events

Comment: Did you try the expression without curly brackets?

Comment: I tried with curly brackets, without curly brackets, with parenthesis, without parenthesis, and all the combinations...

Comment: Move the math inside your controller `ng-show="computeShow(event.date)"`. `{{event.date}}` causes problems.

Comment: I'm going to try this and will comment the results

Comment: Yes, I moved the logic to the controller. There I had to use moment.js, but it worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the math inside the controller

HTML

```html
<section ng-repeat="event in events | orderBy:'date' | filter:myFilter" 
     ng-show="computeShow(event.date)">
```

JS

```
$scope.computeShow = function (eventDate) {
    return (
        //compute eventDate >= today's date
    )
};
```

Comment: As I told you yesterday it works, thank you for your help ;) I voted you positively, but I don't have (reputation >= 15) so I can't score responses yet.